# How to Runn a Website on linux vps

Tags: webserver, centos7, vps

I recently have bought a centos 7 VPS  server and i want to upload my php website to it. It's completely different than a hosting. How should I do it?
It would be appreciated if you explain for me these things
how to connect a domain to my to my VPS
 how to install a webserver on my VPS
where do I upload my files
I also need to upload my SSL certificate where do I upload it

And by the way I don't want to use a control panel like cpanel or other control panels.

Comment: Which webserver you can install on VPS ?

Comment: @ZahidRahman I know nothing about these, where can I check which webserver i can install?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: At first connect your nameserver to your domain.

Step 2: Priliminary setup on your linux vps [Link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-centos-7

Step 3: Install your webserver,specific database,SSL etc. [Checklist Link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tags/centos/tutorials)

Step 4: Then you can upload code on any FTP client or via github(Push Code on your repository and then pull form your VPS).

Comment: I'm absolutely new to VPS, I know nothing about where I can find the nameserver of my vps, would you please share more information about these steps?

Comment: Sorry the link is now correct,please check it out, which company you use vps and domain?